# can anyone have any idea how to do swipe cards up and down scroll animation like mobile depth page transformer scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

[depth page transformer scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMGIm.gif)

```
`I tried using position sticky with top 0`
 `container`
```

```
.gallery{
        width: 35rem;
        height: 22rem;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: auto;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
```

```
`images`
```

```
.gallery img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        object-fit: cover;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
```

```
 `common styling``your text`
```

```
 .gallery, .gallery img{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
```

difficulties:
*first card coming last and last card first
*it is difficult to automate code with api
*scroll speed is high

Comment: Why don't you use some plugin instead? Check this: https://turbofuture.com/computers/React-Image-Sliders

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).